# C++ - 'localtime' this function or variable may be unsafe

Tags: c++, date, datetime, localtime, ctime

I am writing a simple logging class in C++ for learning purposes. My code contains a function that returns a string of today's date. However, I get a compiler error whenever 'localtime' is called.

```
std::string get_date_string(time_t *time) {
    struct tm *now = localtime(time);
    std::string date = std::to_string(now->tm_mday) + std::to_string(now->tm_mon) + std::to_string(now->tm_year);
    return date;
}
```

I have tried using `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. It didn't work and the same error appeared. I also tried putting `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` inside the preprocessor definitions in the project properties. This gave an unresolved external error.

Does anyone have any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Where is the exact warning message? `localtime` can be dangerous to use because it returns a pointer to a memory area which it owns, so if you call it multiple times you need to make sure each time you copy the struct. Also, by the way, the way you create a string, if you get "2112016" you don't know if that's 21/1/2016 or 2/11/2016.

Comment: **Do not use this function** for the reason given in the warning.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before `#include` any other header files, like the following code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <ctime>
//your code
```

Comment: **Do not do this.** Instead take the CRT security warning seriously!

Answer (score 63):

The problem is that `std::localtime` is not thread-safe because it uses a static buffer (shared between threads). Both `POSIX` and `Windows` have safe alternatives: [localtime_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r) and [localtime_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx).

Here is what I do:

```
inline std::tm localtime_xp(std::time_t timer)
{
    std::tm bt {};
#if defined(__unix__)
    localtime_r(&timer, &bt);
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    localtime_s(&bt, &timer);
#else
    static std::mutex mtx;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    bt = *std::localtime(&timer);
#endif
    return bt;
}

// default = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
inline std::string time_stamp(const std::string& fmt = "%F %T")
{
    auto bt = localtime_xp(std::time(0));
    char buf[64];
    return {buf, std::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt.c_str(), &bt)};
}
```

Comment: better answer than the one selected

Answer (score 4):

updated answer with C++20 chrono library

```
    const auto now            = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto time_zone      = std::chrono::current_zone();
    const auto local_time     = time_zone->to_local(now);
    const auto time_point     = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::days>(local_time);
    const auto year_month_day = std::chrono::year_month_day{ time_point };

    int year  = static_cast<int>(year_month_day.year());
    int month = static_cast<unsigned>(year_month_day.month());
    int day   = static_cast<unsigned>(year_month_day.day());
```

Comment: This gives the current UTC date.  You can get the current _local_ date by first transforming `system_clock::now()` to a `local_time` by using `current_zone()->to_local()`.